# What is the meaning of $O(10^{-14})$?

Tags: cosmology, notation, error-analysis, approximations

[image]

[image]

What is the meaning of the symbol,O(1),O(10^-4),in the picture above the text box?
I am not a computer engineer or a computer language major.

Please tell me simply. I don't want an explanation with Taylor series.

Comment: Maybe you could provide the whole text in the book, not just a fraction of it?

Comment: It's not the standard "big $O$ notation", but you needn't know the standard meaning. Here, it means something like "to within a factor of $10$ of".

Comment: @Monopole. The part that deals with the flatness problem. The current density value of a flat universe is set and compared to the density value of the initial universe. In this context, 1-omega(to) = O(1) is written.

Comment: That is very weird indeed because in big-O notation there is literally no difference between $O(1)$ and $O(10^{-4})$ since that gets absorbed by the constant in the definition. Unless this is more cringey physicist abuse of math...

Comment: @The_Sympathizer It’s not cringy to use a common symbol in a different way. That’s like saying Spanish is cringy because its Latin letters are pronounced differently than in English.

Comment: That said, I don't like this O notation since it's a waste of letters... instead of $x = O(1)$ they could just write $x \sim 1$.

Answer (score 5):

It means 'of order' i.e. the approximate size

Comment: @joseph h Thank you for your edit.

Comment: @Buzz Your welcome.

Answer (score 5):

$A = O(1)$ means that $A$ has order of magnitude $10^1$. That means roughly

$$10^{0.5} \lt A \lt 10^{1.5} \\ 3 \lt A \lt 3 \times 10^{1}$$

$A = O(10^{-4})$ means that $A$ has order of magnitude $10^{-4}$. That means roughly

$$10^{-4.5} \lt A \lt 10^{-3.5} \\ 3 \times 10^{-5} \lt A \lt 3 \times 10^{-4}$$

The factor of $3$ here comes from $3 \approx 10^{0.5}$, or in other words, $ 0.5 \approx \log 3$.

Comment: Does .3 mean 0.3?

Comment: Yes it most certainly does.

Comment: Where does the 0.3 or 3 come from?

Comment: @Prahar On a log scale, the series $0.1, 0.3, 1.0, 3.0, 10$ is approximately equally spaced, because $3^2\approx 10$ and $0.3^2\approx 0.1$.

Comment: @Vincent Thacker Thank you for your edits.